# Does JS Selenium API have an Actions class or equivalent?

Tags: javascript, selenium

[This](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/) is the documentation for Selenium API for JS.

I've been looking into all its modules ([`Browser`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_Browser.html), [`Builder`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_Builder.html), [`Button`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_Button.html), [`By`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_By.html), etc.) but I can't find an equivalent for the [Actions API (java)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html), which enables complex gestures.

Is there such an equivalent in JS Selenium API?

Comment: see http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Actions.html

Comment: @FlorentB. this comment should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the Selenium JS API, but most of the other forks like `WebDriverIO` or `Protractor` or `NightWatch` have Actions class in them.

For eg - Here is the Protractor definition of [actions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions).

Comment: Cool! Coincidentally, I use Protractor, so it'll do. Thanks.

Comment: The docs from protractor link you provided (*See the selenium webdriver docs for more details on action sequences.*), although pointing to [broken link](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_ActionSequence.html) suggests that the capability exists in Selenium API.